# how to increase/decrease playback speed on .wav file?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, pydub

i'm trying to increase/decrease the pitch(or speed) on a few `.wav` files in pydub.
I tried using `sound.set_frame_rate` (i multiplied the original frame rate, but nothing changed).
Does anyone know how this can be done? (preferably without downloading additional external libraries). thanks.

Comment: did you assign the result of `sound.set_frame_rate()` to a new var? audio segments are immutable, none of the methods will cause a change, in place (they all return a new audio segment)

Comment: @Jiaaro thanks,i tried that now. it seems to have some effec but only  when i make the frame rate slower (for example 44100/2,44100/6 etc..) but when i make it larger nothing happens. do you know why? also do you know any other effects i can do with pydub?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sound.set_frame_rate()` does a conversion, it should not cause any "chipmunk effect", but what you *can* do is change the frame rate (without a conversion) and then convert the audio from there back to a normal frame rate (like 44.1 kHz, "CD quality")

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_file(…)

def speed_change(sound, speed=1.0):
    # Manually override the frame_rate. This tells the computer how many
    # samples to play per second
    sound_with_altered_frame_rate = sound._spawn(sound.raw_data, overrides={
        "frame_rate": int(sound.frame_rate * speed)
    })

    # convert the sound with altered frame rate to a standard frame rate
    # so that regular playback programs will work right. They often only
    # know how to play audio at standard frame rate (like 44.1k)
    return sound_with_altered_frame_rate.set_frame_rate(sound.frame_rate)

slow_sound = speed_change(sound, 0.75)
fast_sound = speed_change(sound, 2.0)
```

Comment: thnx that worked! could you please explain more in depth what these lines do? `sound_with_altered_frame_rate = sound._spawn(sound.raw_data, overrides={
        "frame_rate": int(sound.frame_rate * speed)
    })
    return sound_with_altered_frame_rate.set_frame_rate(sound.frame_rate)`

Comment: @Sh0z I've added some explanatory comments

Comment: slow down sounds very creepy