# pygame mixer music change playback speed

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I want to playback an *.mp3* file at 50% it's original speed, naturally pitched down (i.e. keeping the pitch is not my requirement).
I am using `pygame.mixer` and found several solutions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159365/pygame-audio-playback-speed)) that suggest changing the frequency on initialization should do the job as shown below, however that does not work for me.

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init(frequency=22050) # my track.mp3 has a 44100 sample rate
mixer.music.load("track.mp3")
mixer.music.play()
```

Am I doing something wrong? No matter to what value i change `frequency` it does not at all change the playback speed or pitch of the music played.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408833/how-to-increase-decrease-playback-speed-on-wav-file) here, with which I am able to speed down my track and play it back using `mixer.Sound(speed_change(sound, 0.5).raw_data()).play()`, however this method does not allow me to use the `mixer.music` functionality such as `seek(time)` or setting the start time when using `.play()`.

I am generally also open to solutions that are not using pygame mixer, however I do need to be able to stop and/or pause the playback and have a seek functionality.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use this Audio Slowdown Software.][1](https://audiotrimmer.com/audio-speed-changer/)

This would have the advantage of being easily reusable without having to type extra code or extra lines.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that's actually not at all want i want to achieve, as i am building a toll with which i want to be able to  change the audio to varying speeds during playback